# Generating a desired number combination using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I’ve given a set of numbers

```
1  2  3
```

I need to generate number with just 3 like
`3 3 3`
Normally if I let the program to generate all the probable combination it'll be kinda like

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
3 2 1 and so on....
```

and after all of the combination I'll get `3 3 3` at some point.

but I don't want the result to be like that, I want the program to be like, when ever one 3 appears it’ll automatically change the other digits.

as example, after generatig

```
1 2 3
```

I want the next combination to be in 1 and 2 and, 3 will remain unchanged.
as like,`1 3 3` and then `3 3 3`
how can write such program using python?

Comment: I'm not sure I enderstood your problem.
For example, you have `1 2 4 5 3`, then, step 2 : `1 2 4 3 3`, then `1 2 3 3 3`, `1 3 3 3 3`,  and finally `3 3 3 3 3` ?

Comment: Hi @Tri Circle can you make your post somewhat clearer. What is the objective you want to achieve here? Do you want to generate numbers of size 3 only or can it be variable sizes. If you want to generate numbers like `3 3 3` why going through all the hassle of passing from `1 2 3` to ` 1 3 3` and  `3 3 3` but not going directly to `3 3 3`? What is the order of changes you want to have? It is not clear enough!

Comment: @totok  yes, you got it right.

Comment: @Thomas, I'm trying to simulate a Artificial life simulation of evolution. such as evolution keeps changing our genome in random, but while it prduce a parfect genom the evolution keeps changing other genomes except the parfet ones. just like from a random set of 1 2 3 4 numbers I’m supposing 3 is the perfect, so whenever the program produce a combination like 1 2 3 4 it wont change the 3 in but will keep changing 1 2 - 4 until if generated 3 3 3 3

Comment: Okay much clearer now, please include this explanation in your question, such that everyone can follow your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

So a possible solution you could have is to separate each number into its own variable, then have it check the variables each pass. If a variable is equal to 3, it doesn't need ot change, and prints out the same output until all of the variables equal 3.

You could put them into a while loop to do this. For example:

```
var1 = 0
var2 = 0
var3 = 0

condition = False
while condition is not True:
       # Iterate over each variable until it's 3, then hold it.
```

If you're getting input entered in, instead of setting the 3 variables yourself, you can ask to separate them by commas, then enter them in:

```
var1, var2, var3 = [int(x) for x in input("Enter 3 values: ").split(', ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions for you

## Solution 1 : replace forward

We replace each value of the array with a recursive call, and stop when we find the first wanted value

```
def replace_forward(array, value, index=0):
    if index < len(array):
        if array[index] != value:
            array = replace_forward(array, value, index + 1)
        array[index] = value
    return array

testArrays = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],    # Nominal
    [1, 4, 5, 10, 3],   # 3 at the end
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], # No 3
    [],                 # Empty
    [3, 1, 2, 4],       # 3 at the begining
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6] # More than one 3 in the list
]

print("Testing the replace_forward method : ")
for array in testArrays:
    print("{} -> {}".format(array, replace_forward(array.copy(), 3)))
```

Output :

```
Testing the replace_forward method : 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 4, 5, 10, 3] -> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7] -> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[] -> []
[3, 1, 2, 4] -> [3, 1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6] -> [3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6
```

## Solution 2 : replace backwards

We replace starting by the end, so we don't stop at the "first" wanted value found. I didn't write a recursive method so you can see the two code patterns, but you can easily change it to optimize it and remove this awful `for` loop.

```
def replace_backwards(array, value):
    replace = False
    for i in range(len(array) - 1, -1, -1):
        if array[i] == value:
            replace = True
        if replace:
            array[i] = value
    return array

testArrays = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],    # Nominal
    [1, 4, 5, 10, 3],   # 3 at the end
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], # No 3
    [],                 # Empty
    [3, 1, 2, 4],       # 3 at the begining
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6] # More than one 3 in the list
]

print("Testing the replace_forward method : ")
for array in testArrays:
    print("{} -> {}".format(array, replace_forward(array.copy(), 3)))
```

Output:

```
Testing the replace_backwards method : 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 4, 5, 10, 3] -> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7] -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[] -> []
[3, 1, 2, 4] -> [3, 1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6] -> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6]
```